# Regex to accept only 5 numbers and then a dash or a letter on typescript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, unicode-escapes

I am dealing with an issue with Regex.
I have a input which has maxLength 10.

I achieved till now to have the first given value can be digits for example 12345 but then it waits for a dash and after it you can write a letter or again a number maxLength=10 for example: 12345-a121 is allowed and it works with the currrent

But I want to be possible after the 5 digits to be allowed letters or dash because for the moment with this regex it is allowed only dash after 5 digits.
For example 12345a or 12345- to be allowed.
This is the actual regex what I am using.

```
Valid/Matches: 12345a235, 123a, 12345-aa1, 12345a, 12345-a.  

Not Valid/Does not matches: -11, 111111, aaaa, 

(?=^[^W_]{1,5}-[^W_]{1,8}$)^.{1,10}$|^[^W_]{1,5}$
```

I am debugging on the regex101.com but I am not finding a way for that to allow.
12345a for example

This is the condition to check if it matches or not.

```
if (!this.value.toString().match('^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$') && this.value.toString()) {
      return ValidationInfo.errorCode("You need to do something");
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Could you provide explain more and provide more valid and invalid examples?

Comment: @youdateme Yes I have updated my question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it's up to 5 numbers, an optional dash, then more optional letters or numbers, with a maximum length of 10?

Comment: @youdateme right.

Comment: @youdateme up 5 numbers optional dash or letter it should have then numbers.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... how about the limit of the terminating character sequence. I did miss it since I immediately went for the valid/invalid examples of yours. And I also realize that both expressions can be written even simpler without the lookahead.

Comment: @PeterSeliger The problem it is that I need to show particular errors if for example the input ends with dash or it starts with letter.
Btw the regex ^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$ it is throwing me error saying that for example 1234a does not match.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... you need to set the correct flag. Since the expressions features unicode escapes the regex for your use case is ... `/^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$/u`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger still not working, If I write 1a it throws the error, weird because on the regex101 it says that this matches.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... countercheck your environment(s) with [*"Can I use unicode property escapes ?"*](https://caniuse.com/?search=unicode%20property%20escapes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit** since the patterns of the first approach can be simplified and also were missing the limitations of the ending sequence's length.*

- for matching only with `Letter` unicode property escapes

  - [`/^\d{1,5}[-\p{L}][-\p{L}\d]{0,9}$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/3)
- matching and capturing with `Letter` unicode property escapes

  - [`/^(?<digitsOnly>\p{N}{1,5})(?<miscellaneous>[-\p{L}][-\p{L}\p{N}]{0,9})$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/4)

*Example code ...*

```js
const multilineSample = `12345a235
123a
12345-aa1
12345a
12345-a

12-a235dkfsf
12-a235dkfsfs

123a-dssava-y
123a-dssava-1a

12345-aa1--asd-
12345-aa1--asd-s

-11
111111
aaaa`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/3]
const regXJustMatch = /^\d{1,5}[-\p{L}][-\p{L}\d]{0,9}$/gmu;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/4]
const regXNamedGroups =
  /^(?<digitsOnly>\p{N}{1,5})(?<miscellaneous>[-\p{L}][-\p{L}\p{N}]{0,9})$/gmu;

console.log(
  'matches only ...',
  multilineSample.match(regXJustMatch)
);
console.log(
  'matches and captures ...', [
    ...multilineSample.matchAll(regXNamedGroups)
  ]
  .map(({ 0: match, groups }) => ({ match, ...groups }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

---

***1st approach***

- straightforward and plain ... [`/^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/1)
- with named capture groups ... [`/^(?<digitsOnly>\p{N}{1,5}(?!\p{N}+))(?<miscellaneous>[-\p{L}\p{N}]+)$/u`](https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/2)

For both variants it is obvious to start with ...

- a digit sequence of at least 1 and up to 5 digits ...

  - traditional ... `^\d{1,5}`
  - [unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes) ... `^\p{N}{1,5}`

It's also clear, one wants to end with a character sequence of any of dash and/or word. Due to having to exclude `_` one can not just use the `\w` escape for letters and digits since `\w` covers/includes `_` as well. But one could use [unicode property escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes), thus ...

- a regex covering the end of a line with a valid character class is ...

  - already mixed ... `[-\p{L}\d]+$`
  - mostly unicode escapes ... `[-\p{L}\p{N}]+)$`

A combined regex like ... `/^\d{1,5}[-\p{L}\d]+$/u` ... almost covers the requirements but fails for `111111` which of cause gets matched even though it shouldn't according to the requirements.

A [negative lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#negative-lookahead) ... `(?!\d+)` respectively `(?!\p{N}+)` ... which follows the starting digit sequence does prevent any other (terminating) digit-only sequence, thus `123456` does not get matched anymore.

*Example code ...*

```js
const multilineSample = `12345a235
123a
12345-aa1
12345a
12345-a

-11
111111
aaaa`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/1]
const regXJustMatch = /^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$/gmu;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/zPkcwv/2]
const regXNamedGroups =
  /^(?<digitsOnly>\p{N}{1,5}(?!\p{N}+))(?<miscellaneous>[-\p{L}\p{N}]+)$/gmu;

console.log(
  'matches only ...',
  multilineSample.match(regXJustMatch)
);
console.log(
  'matches and captures ...', [
    ...multilineSample.matchAll(regXNamedGroups)
  ]
  .map(({ 0: match, groups }) => ({ match, ...groups }))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If I try `^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$` and then check if it matches or not I am getting error that saying 1a does not match with this regex.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... you need to set the correct flag. Since the expressions features unicode escapes the regex for your use case is ... `/^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$/u`.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... maybe you also come up with a set of valid/invalid sequences which cover the edge cases. Thus one can see the exact requirements.

Comment: I have added some valid/invalid edge cases.
With the regex that I have said on my question it works everything fine till the part if I write 11111a, this part does not work.
But If I write 11111-a or 111a it works.

Comment: @Abedin.Zhuniqi ... `11111a` matches with any of the so far provided 4 above linked versions though. And did you already check whether your environment supports unicode property escapes?

Comment: actually this should be the right thing as you have mentioned `/^\d{1,5}(?!\d+)[-\p{L}\d]+$/u` but I cannot check it anymore because the VPN it does not work on another laptop so I don't have any access.